# How can I selectively enable a 3rd party drive SDK based application for a domain?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing an application using the Drive API, and only want that app to be selectively whitelisted rather than all 3rd party Drive API based apps.

Is there a way to whitelist the app without listing it in the enterprise apps marketplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to whitelist specific apps for a domain. Good feature request though.

Comment: Hi Steve - thanks for the response.

This feature would also be a lifesaver when we are asking security conscious customers to try our product. Right now some of them have drive access off, and even if they are open to a trial with us, they are concerned about enabling arbitrary drive applications.